# inheriting model and providing new model gives error when creating records in the inherited model- OpenERP 7

Tags: python, inheritance, odoo, openerp-7

In OpenERP v7, I need to get all the fields of res.partner model in the travel.partner model

```
class travel_partner(osv.osv):
    _name = "travel.partner"
    _inherit = "res.partner"
```

When creating records in "travel.partner" model works fine. but when trying to create a partner record or user or company gives following error

```
AttributeError: 'Field image not found in browse_record(travel.partner, 68)'
```

How can i solve this? or is there any alternate solution other than re coding all the fields to the new table?

Comment: Please show your xml view for this new model in which you have added fields.

Comment: Can you add the definition of the `image` field as well?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. : I just copied the basic res.partner view defined in base module. Changed the model and name. No other change.

Comment: @ChesuCR : I tried defining the image field to the travel.partner also

Answer (score 0):

You can try by defining relation between travel.partner and res.partner same as **product.template** and **product.product** by adding `_inherits` not _inherit, it will allow you to access all the parent fields in child model.

At current situation I can not say anything without looking your entire code because logically nothing is wrong in your question, so it's better if you should add all the details or just implement another one.

Because when you create res.partner is must not to go for travel.partner as it's child of res.partner.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.
The error was because of the functional field with store condition. In res.partner, there were fields image_medium and image_small using store conditions with key as res.partner. In my new model,I re defined the code with store condition  key changed to travel.partner which fixed the issue